# Can maven run command line instructions?

Tags: maven-2

Can we bind some native OS commands to the maven goals and/or phases?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually there is the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) for these cases.

Comment: It answer was selected, because it resolves my problem. But in question I'd took about any comand, not only java tasks.

Answer (score 9):

See [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) for details

Comment: I guess he can find that link from the page I provided already

Answer (score 5):

Not natively.

However, by using the [AntRun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/), you can specify an Ant task (using [Exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)) that execute a OS command during the build.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase> <!-- a lifecycle phase --> </phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>

                <!--
                  Place any Ant task here. You can add anything
                  you can add between <target> and </target> in a
                  build.xml.
                -->

              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```